# How does SharePoint Designer interact with core?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, spservices, content-database

When an user does some changes like changing background color or adding an image for `Home.aspx` via `SharePoint Designer` what actually happens at this moment? In other words what happens under the hood? Let me guess - may be `SharePoint Designer` uses `server client object`, or windows service for editing, updating data in `WSS_Content`.

I will be very glad to get any explanation or helpful links.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right just for more informations :

There is two page state **Ghosted** and **Unghosted**

**Ghosting** is the state on which pages are rendered from the File System.

**Unghosting** is the stage where the edited pages reside in the database and are rendered from there.

> **Note :** **Application page** is always **ghosted**, but **Site pages** can be **ghosted** or **unghosted** (if changes have made through
>   **SharePoint Designer**).

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, may be you know how I can programmatically edit like changing background color an aspx page ?

Comment: You can create your own **css** file and reference it in your application page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that SharePoint Designer is a very old application and pre-dates all of the remote APIs we have now. If you [Fiddle](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) the traffic sent to and from SPD you'll see calls to an endpoint called owssvr.dll, which is a long-deprecated service but still present and in use in a number of cases. This is how Designer is able to communicate its changes back to the server.

I haven't done this in a long time, probably the 2010 version, but I have to believe it still works the same way.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/using-owssvrdll-to-retrieve-list-data.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. SP Designer is not required. I just try to get some information how I can edit(create) an aspx page programmatically. I have backuped file system and SP database and now I need to recreate(restore) my sharepoint to a new host programmatically. I can't do this neither by csom nor ssom. So I just want to repeat changes made by SPDesigner. Can me advise something ?

Comment: In your question, you should ask for the stuff you actually want to know. "How can I edit or create a SharePoint page programmatically" is a completely different question than the one you asked.